# turn clicked on object id into a variable with jquery to optimize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hello I was wondering if there was a way to get something clicked on like for here I want to make it so that when one of the images gets clicked on I can turn the id of it into a variable and from there do an if statement so that I can fadeOut all the other boxes and fadeIn after using the variable. Otherwise I will have to make 6 seperate functions by having there id clicked which will make it a lot more code 
I think this is a way to optimize it not sure if there is a better way to optimise this code considering this might be replicated 6 times I basically want a way to merge them into one. I appreciate any and all assistance have been looking at this for a while but cant seem to figure it out maybe getting another perspective will help

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".catalignleft").click(function() {


        function complete() {
          jQuery(".alignleft");
        }

        if(status == 1) {
            jQuery("#box1").fadeOut();
            jQuery("#box2").fadeOut();
            jQuery("#box3").fadeOut();
            jQuery("#box4").fadeOut();
            jQuery("#box5").fadeOut();
            jQuery("#box6").fadeOut();
            jQuery("#box1").fadeIn();
            status--;
        } else{
        jQuery("#box1").fadeIn(1600, "linear", complete);
status++;
}



    });

    jQuery("#btn2").click(function() {
    jQuery("#box1").fadeOut();

    jQuery("#log").empty();
    });
    jQuery(".blocked a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  jQuery('<div/>')
});


    jQuery("#btn2").click(function() {

    jQuery("#box2").fadeOut();
    jQuery("#log").empty();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a class selector instead of an ID selector, and put a `$(this).fadeIn` in their `fadeOut` callback, like this:

```
$(".box").click(function() {
    $(".box").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

(Assuming all your boxes have a class of "box"):

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

Also, there's no reason to be using `jQuery(...)`. You can shorten it to `$(...)` and save yourself some typing.

Comment: I would but wordpress does not allow it :D
But seems reasonable was trying to figure it out and I did know of this  but it just did not occur to me to use it that way thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As Elliot showed in his answer, you can reference the current object (in this case, the clicked one) by using *this* (even if you're not using jQuery).

Comment: Hey Zim, I think this belongs in a comment. =)

Comment: True. I can't add it as a comment under your post (nor under the question). Maybe I need a bit more of reputation? I'll consider it. Thanks for your feedback :)